# Does there exist a surjective homomorphism $f:M/N\to L$ if $L\not\subset N$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, quotient-spaces

This may seem like a really obvious question, but I am doubting myself. Suppose $M$ is an $R$-module, for some ring $R$. If $N$ is a submodule then obviously we have the quotient module $M/N$. Now suppose $L$ is some non-zero cyclic submodule of $M/N$, i.e. generated by a single element that is not in $N$. Then can we construct a surjective homomorphism $f:M/N\to L$?

I would imagine that we would perhaps need to impose some restrictions onto $R$.

Comment: It seems that you need an element in $M/N$ whose order is infinite; or finite and a multiple of the order of the generator of $L$.

Comment: Well let's say $L$ is generated by $l$. As $l\in M$ but $l\not\in N$, can I not just map $l+N\to l$?

Comment: If for some $n\in\Bbb N$, $nl\in N$ but $nl\neq 0$ in $M$, then this map won't be surjective.

Comment: Ah yes of course. So if I can show $rl\not\in N$ for any $r\in R$, or if $rl\in N$ then $rl=0$ in $M$, then the above map will be surjective?

Comment: I'm no expert on modules, but I'd say so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Take $R = \mathbb Z$, $M = \mathbb Q$, $N = 0$, and $L = \mathbb Z$ (the usual subset of $\mathbb Q$).

Comment: Actually, $N$ can be any subgroup of $\mathbb{Q}$